# Is it possible to dynamically set a components @Input at run-time?

Tags: angular

Say I have a `dynamic-component-wrapper` that can instantiate any `Component` class that is passed into it.

```
// DRE013 DCOOKE 16/05/2017 - The component to instantiate.
@Input() componentType: Type<{}>;

// DRE013 DCOOKE 16/05/2017 - the component that will be created
private _cmpRef: ComponentRef<Component>;


// DRE013 DCOOKE 16/05/2017 - Creates a component ref in the view at #target
createComponent(){

    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.componentType);
    this._cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
    //this._cmpRef.instance.inputs >>>>>>>>> this is a string[] and I do not see how I can use this 
}
```

Example usage

```
<shared-dynamic-component [componentType]="TestComponent"></shared-dynamic-component>
```

Where
`TestComponent = TestComponent //class`

This works as expected, and I can receive an instance of this component from within the `dynamic-component-wrapper` like so:

`this._cmpRef.instance`

The [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html#!#instance-anchor) are not clear on this `instance` object - simply stating that instance is of type `C` - with absolutely no reference to what C actually is.

Thankfully my IDE was able to tell me that :

`ComponentRef.instance` has the following properties:

- `inputs : string[]`
- `outputs : string[]`

However I do not understand how I am meant to use this information. I'd imagine this is just the **names** of the `@Input` fields - but I cannot think how I can pass in a complex object as an Input.

### Question

Is it possible for me to set the `@Inputs` and other **meta-data** after dynamically creating a component with the `componentFactoryResolver`?

Comment: `C` is a generic type parameter, because T was used elsewhere in this class I guess.

Comment: _Is it possible for me to set the @Inputs_ - do you want them to be updated automatically by Angular?

Comment: @Maximus that would be ideal - It sounds a tad far-fetched I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Automatic update

This doesn't seem to be possible. Here is the explanation why.

For each component, Angular compiler creates a factory. You can observe all factories in the `sources` tab under `ng://` folder, [here is the example](https://hackernoon.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e#8901) of how it looks. When it creates a factory, it defines `nodes` that will be rendered inside this component view. Some of the nodes are child components.

And it is at the time of generating this factory it is defined which input properties the framework should track. So unless you defined input properties before the compilation, Angular will not be tracking and updating the inputs.

Here is an example of how this factory looks like:

```
function View_AppComponent_0(l) {
  return jit_viewDef2(0,[
    jit_queryDef3(201326592,1,{someComp: 0}),
    (l()(),jit_elementDef4(0,null,null,1,'h1',[],null,null,null,null,null)),
    (l()(),jit_textDef5(null,[
      'Hello ',
      ''
    ]
    )),
    (l()(),jit_textDef5(null,['\n\n'])),
    (l()(),jit_elementDef4(0,null,null,1,'b-comp',[],null,null,null,jit_View_BComponent_06,jit__object_Object_7)),

      *************************************
      // this is a child component's node definition which has `some` property binding
      jit_directiveDef8(24576,null,0,jit_BComponent9,[],{some: [
        0,
        'some'  <------------------------ property name to track
      ]
    },null)
     **************************************************

  ]
```

When you use `this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory`, it actually searches for that factory. It doesn't compile anything.

### Manual update

This certainly possible. You can query a child component from the parent component and update the property - it will be correctly rendered in the child component's template. And you can even trigger onChanges lifecycle hook.

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(BComponent) bc;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.bc.some = 'foo';
      const changes = {some: new SimpleChange('', 'foo', true)};
      this.bc.ngOnChanges(changes);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Some great information here +1 . This is kind of what I assumed anyway. Will accept this as an answer if no one else can chime in.

Comment: @DanielCooke, sure, I've added some information regarding manual update. Also, you might find interesting all Angular articles [on my blog](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi), they are quite informative and in-depth

Comment: brilliant - followed your blog. This is exactly the kind of resource I've been looking for.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. However, my dynamic component has two inputs. One of which receives the passed in parameter, as explained above. The other does not, even though I pass it the same way in the next statement. The working input is a "number" while the failing one is a "string", I doubt this is the problem. Using `console.log` at the time the values are set, indicates the failing input is correctly set. But `console.log` inside the target component returns `undefined`.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. I was passing the inputs through an intermediate component, not directly. I simply failed to update the intermediate component's inputs - which means I can drop the direct updates (which do not work, as I merely have a class instance, not a component instance).

Comment: @MaxWizardK does it work for a dynamically component (created using resolveComponentFactory) without ViewChild ?

Comment: @MaxWizardK 
I dynamically created component using resolveComponentFactory (this component have two views based on a variable(@Input "VAR_X")
The parent component (where i created the dynamic component) has a button, its goal is to change the value of the variable "VAR_X" : for that i did this "componentRef.instance['VAR_X'] = 'view2'.
This changes the value of the variable "VAR_X" of the dynamic component but it does not change the display.
I hope it's clearer now and thanks in advance

Comment: @aguetat, yes, I understand now, it should work. I need more details. Can you create a separate question with all the details and post a link here, I'll take a look

Comment: @MaxWizardK, it works now, i had a bug elsewhere. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating a class to do so... incase this helps anyone else.

## Usage

```js
const componentChangeBuilder = new DynamicComponentChangeBuilder(componentRef);
componentChangeBuilder.addInput('inputName', 'some string value');
componentChangeBuilder.addInput('someOtherInputName', 1234);
componentChangeBuilder.commit();
```

```js
import { ComponentRef, OnChanges, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Use this to track and trigger ngOnChanges for dynamically loaded components.
 */
export class DynamicComponentChangeBuilder<TComponent = any> {
    private readonly componentRef: ComponentRef<TComponent>; 
    private readonly inputs = new Map<keyof TComponent, TComponent[keyof TComponent]>();
    private readonly changesHistory = {} as SimpleChanges;

    constructor(componentRef: ComponentRef<TComponent>) {
        this.componentRef = componentRef;        
    }

    public addInput(
        input: keyof TComponent,
        value: TComponent[typeof input],
    ): void {
        this.inputs.set(input, value);
    }

    public commit() {
        const currentChanges = {} as SimpleChanges;

        this.inputs.forEach((newValue, input) => {
            const previousChange = this.changesHistory[input as string];
            let currentChange: SimpleChange;
            if (!!previousChange) {
                currentChange = {
                    previousValue: previousChange.currentValue,
                    currentValue: newValue,
                    firstChange: false,
                } as SimpleChange;
            } else {
                currentChange = {
                    currentValue: newValue,
                    firstChange: true,
                } as SimpleChange;
            }

            this.changesHistory[input as string] = currentChange;
            currentChanges[input as string] = currentChange;
            this.componentRef.instance[input] = currentChange.currentValue;
        });

        if (implementsOnChanges(this.componentRef.instance)) {
            this.componentRef.instance.ngOnChanges(currentChanges);
        }
    }
}

function implementsOnChanges(component: any): component is OnChanges {
    return (component as OnChanges)?.ngOnChanges !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: Ehhh, I'd like to try this out. What's the license of your code here?

Comment: Nvm, I found out all code is Creative Commons that is posted on StackOverflow, good to know. Thank you very much for this! I made a few changes, instead of `ComponentRef<TComponent>` I just use `TComponent` and instead of `.instance` I just use the componentRef directly. Since I don't have a copy of the Component Ref, just the instance from ViewChild. Overall this works really well, thank you again!